# How can I specify the JDK in IntelliJ for storing in Git?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Question 1: Is it possible to specify JDK for an [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) project for storing in Git? Currently, I have to clone an IntelliJ Java project from Git and then manually set up JDK in Project Structure. Is it possible to get the JDK automatically set up (selected) for the project in IntelliJ upon project cloning from Git?

Also, related question 2: why do we need to set up the JDK in IntelliJ for the project if we specify the JDK version in the [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file, so it could be selected for the project automatically from those JDKs registered with IntelliJ?

Comment: "why do we need to set up JDK in Intellij for the project if we specify JDK version in Maven POM file" - There are several reasons.  One is that the POM may not say anything about which JDK to use but instead may indicate which version of source code to support and which version of bytecode to generate, which is related but separate.  Another is the POM doesn't indicate where the JDK is.

Comment: If you have a jdk registered which can do what is requested in the Pom, it should happen automatically

Comment: Git just stores commits, which just store files and metadata. What versions of what languages and systems and so on: those are up to other programs *interpreting* the commits and/or files. Git is not involved here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer question 1., it's possible to specify the *language level* in the pom, such as "1.8" but it's not possible to specify the specific build of the JDK (e.g. 1.8.0_301) in the pom.

This allows a "general" language level definition that correctly uses java code from different language levels (Overrides, diamonds, lambdas, etc) whilst at the same time allowing you to upgrade the JDK (security update?) at any time without breaking your build.

Remember also that JDK's are platform dependent, and your java code is *portable* - it should compile and run on PC, linux and Mac. Specifying a JDK only available for windows would break the concept of portability (which is one of the reasons why java is in such widespread use)

Question 2. If you already have set up the JDK for the language level you need, you don't need to do it again. Just because the maven pom says "Java 12" doesn't mean that IntelliJ is smart enough to go and download the correct JDK version - you need to do that ;)

In any case, setting up java 12 is a one-off activity for all your projects (and then updates from time to time) - so don't sweat it too much.

Comment: "setting up java 12 is a one-off activity for all your projects" - It's one-off for when you git-clone the project first time. If you need to re-clone it again, you would need to not forget to change JDK for the project, and you need to "manually" specify the project's JDK in the project readme as a prerequisite. It's not too bad, however I thought there could be more reliable approach. Eg, I forget to change JDK for the freshly cloned project and getting build errors and then figuring - oh, it might have something to do with project JDK and there is some time lost already on this.

Comment: Welcome to the day-to-day life of being a java developer ;)